# echo $variable that contains unknown numbers of $ signs?

Tags: php, escaping, echo

imagine we have a variable that contains multiple `$` signs:

```
$variable="$xtttt$yddd$hhh"
```

when I echo the variable I get the following:

```
ttttdddhh
```

this happened because it deals with $X,$y and $h as empty variables, I know I can solve this by escaping each `$` sign:

```
 $variable="\$xtttt\$yddd\$hhh"
```

but the problem that I don't know the number of `$` signs

Note: this happened with shell script too

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just replace all the $ signs with \$ to escape it

```
<?php

$newValue = str_replace("$", "\$" ,$variable); 
echo $newValue;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP would only try to parse variables inside strings defined using "double quotes", but not if they are defined using single 'quotes'.

This is useful tip to avoid extra concatenation. The following examples provide the same output.

```
$foo = $var . ' something ' . $etc;
$foo = "$var something $etc";
```

You can also have array values and object properties parsed,

```
$foo = "Something: {$array['key']}";
$foo = "Something: {$object->property}";
```

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a simple str_replace:

```
$Var = str_replace("$","\$",$var");
```

Or even simpler. Change your quotes from double (`"`) to single (`'`). This would force PHP to read the values literal as plain text to then be parsed into your shell and validated correctly. So:

```
$Var = "$xdjdjj$vvsso$vvvk";
```

Can Change to:

```
$Var = '$xdjdjj$vvsso$vvvk';
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use single quotes (if the origin of your variable content allows it, of course). See this example:

```
$variable="$xtttt$yddd$hhh";   // reports missing vars
$variable2='$xtttt$yddd$hhh';  // works just fine

echo $variable, "\n", $variable2;
```

http://ideone.com/i3e10y

Comment: Should be the same, no?